# What does this line means(in cpp context) list[i].push_back(adj[i][j]);

Tags: c++, graph

What does this line means: **list[i].push_back(adj[i][j]);** ?

```
vector<vector<int>>printGraph(int V, vector<int> adj[])
    {
    vector<vector<int>>list(V);
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
        list[i].push_back(i);
         for(int j=0;j<adj[i].size();j++)
         {
             list[i].push_back(adj[i][j]);
         }
    }
    return list;
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and its [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method? If not start there.

Comment: It is a function call.

Comment: Place j-th element from i-th vector from `adj[]` at the end of i-th vector in the `list`.

Comment: Off topic, but "printGraph" is a *very* misleading name for that function.

Comment: `vector<int> adj[]` isnt something you would actually use. It is strange to see that and `vector<vector<int>>` in the same code. I suppose you found such code online, that doesnt mean that it is good code. There is lots of really bad tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `adj` is a pointer to a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)(and in this case, I suspect it should be taken as a two-dimensional array), and `list` is just a vector of vectors, and therefore a two-dimensional array. `list[i]` is simply a reference to the i-th row of the array `list`, `adj[i][j]` is a reference to the value stored in cell **[i][j]** of the two-dimensional array `adj`. The [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method simply adds the passed value to the end of the corresponding vector, which means the expression `list[i].push_back(adj[i][j]);` will simply add the value stored in the cell `adj[i][j]` to the end of the line `list[i]`

Comment: if we assume adj as pointer to two-dimensional array, then why it's datatype here is vector<int>?

Comment: `adj` probably points to a one dimensional array. `adj[i][j]` accesses j-th element in one of the vectors

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number As I understand code, adj is pointing to 1 dimentional array of vectors of int, so its like 2-d array of ints

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function that return a nested vector as output. The variable list was defined as nested vector in function and as general explanation i could say that two dimensional array represent as vector of vectors in addition with the index of row in the first position of inner peer vector. And the statement:

```
   list[i].push_back(adj[i][j]);
```

add the elements of two dimensional array to inner vector i'th. push_back method add an element to end of vector.

Answer (score 0):

**list[i].push_back(adj[i][j]);**
Here list is the vector of vectors (2D array) that is going to store the adjacency list.
**Example-**
list[1] = [2,3]

list[2] = [1,3]

list[3] = [1,2]